# Ember Routing/Lookup with Attributes other than ID

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I thought I had a fairly simple solution to `find` models with attributes other than ID, but I'm running into one problem.

#### Current setup:

Ember Router:

```coffee
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "posts", ->
    @route "show", {path: ':slug'}

App.PostsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  serialize: (model, params) ->
    object = {}
    name = params[0]
    object[name] = model.get('slug')
    return object
  model: (params) -> App.Post.find(params.slug)
```

Rails Controller:

```ruby
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    render json: @post
  end
end
```

#### THE PROBLEM

If `params.slug == "some-post"`, when `post` object is returned from the server, `post.id == "some-post"`. This messes up all the associations.

This is probably because `DS.Store` is assuming that if I call `find(something)`, `something` is the `id`. I would have expected that the response from the server would overwrite this assumption, but it doesn't.

Is there a better way to do this? My use case is extremely simple. All I need to do is serialize and deserialize a `post` object by the slug attribute.

I'm using Ember Data revision 11

Comment: have you already tried `App.Post.find('slug': params.slug)` instead of `App.Post.find(params.slug)`? also, using an `ActiveModel::Serializer` instead of a serialize function on the ember side might help.

Comment: I'm using `ActiveModel::Serializer`. The solution was to use `findQuery` and `then` function on the returned promise. Answering my own question below.

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be `findQuery`. I was using this some time ago, but I didn't know how to make use of the promise.

```
model: (params) ->
  @get('store').findQuery(App.Post, {slug: params.slug}).then (data) ->
    return data.get('firstObject')
```

and on the rails side:

```ruby
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = params[:slug] ? Post.where(slug: params[:slug]) : Post.homepage
    render json: @posts
  end
```